p-powers in p-adic local fields
I'm looking at $p$-th powers in a local field with the residue characteristic $p$, and I have a contradiction between computer experiments (using two different computer algebra systems) and theoretical reasoning. Hence, I would appreciate it if someone could have a look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathfrak{p}$ its prime ideal dominating some prime number $p$. Next, $K_\mathfrak{p}$ is the completion of $K$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ (i.e., a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) and $O_\mathfrak{p}$ its valuation ring. Further, let $e$ be the ramification index of $\mathfrak{p}$, $ord_{\mathfrak{p}}$ the normalized valuation associated to $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\pi$ a uniformizing element.
The following lemma is extracted from the proof of Artin's theorem in [1, page 77].
Lemma. For every unit $a\in K_\mathfrak{p}$ and every $k\geq 2e + 1$ one has
$$
1 + a\cdot \pi^k \in O_\mathfrak{p}^p.
$$
Proof. Consider the degree~$p$ polynomial
$$
f = x^p - (1 + a\pi^k).
$$
Then, $f' = p x^{p-1}$ and so we have
$$
ord_{\mathfrak{p}} f(1) = k
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
ord_{\mathfrak{p}} f'(1) = ord_{\mathfrak{p}} p = e.
$$
By assumption $k\geq 2e + 1$. Hence, $ord_{\mathfrak{p}} f(1) > 2e = ord_{\mathfrak{p}} \bigl(f'(1)\bigr)^2$. Replacing valuations with the associated norms we write
$$
\bigl| f(1) \bigr| < \bigl| f'(1)^2 \bigr|.
$$
Therefore, [2, Proposition II.2.2] (or, alternatively [1, Theorem 1.79]) asserts that there is a root $b$ of $f$ such that
$$
| b - 1| \leq \bigl| {f(1)}/{f'(1)^2} \bigr| < 1.
$$
In particular, $1 + a\pi^k = b^p\in O_{\mathfrak{p}}^p$ as expected.
QED
In particular, if $a$ is a unit and there is some unit $b$ such that $ord_{\mathfrak{p}} (a - b^p) \geq 2e + 1$, then $a$ must be a $p$-th power in $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Now, consider an explicit example (computations performed independently using computer algebra systems: Magma and Sage). Take $p = 3$ and the number field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a root of $x^{20} + 12 x^{15} + 36 x^{10} + 324$. Take ${\mathfrak{p}}$ the unique prime ideal over $p$, and $\theta$ is its uniformizer. The ramification index of ${\mathfrak{p}}$ equals $e = 5$. Take $a = 1 + \theta^{11}$ and a unit $b$ (rather complicated, found by a brute force search):
\begin{multline*}
b := -\theta^{19} + \frac{1}{5} \theta^{18} + \frac{3}{5} \theta^{17} - \frac{1}{5} \theta^{16} - \frac{7}{5} \theta^{15} - \frac{9}{5} \theta^{14} + \frac{7}{5} \theta^{13} - \frac{6}{5} \theta^{12} + \frac{7}{5} \theta^{11}\\ 
+ \frac{1}{5} \theta^{10} - \frac{4}{5} \theta^{9} - \frac{6}{5} \theta^{8} + \theta^{7} + \frac{9}{5} \theta^{6} - \frac{9}{5} \theta^{5} + \frac{3}{5} \theta^{4} - \frac{3}{5} \theta - \frac{4}{5}
\end{multline*}
Then, both Magma and Sage claim that $ord_{\mathfrak{p}} (a - b^p) = 11 > 10 = 2e$. Hence, $a$ must be a cube in $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
On the other hand, we we extend $K$ to $L := K\bigl(\sqrt[3]{a}\bigr)$, then ${\mathfrak{p}}$ factors in $L$ as ${\mathfrak{p}} = \mathfrak{P}_1\cdot \mathfrak{P}_2^2$. Thus, $L$ cannot embeded into $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Consequently, $a$ may not be a cube in $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$. We've got a contradiction! Where did I make a mistake?
References:
[1] P. Clark,  Pete L. Clark. Algebraic number theory II: Valuations, local fields and adeles. lecture notes, http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/8410FULL.pdf, 2010.
[2]  Serge Lang. Algebraic number theory, volume 110 of Graduate Texts in Mathematics.
Springer-Verlag, New York, second edition, 1994.
Here are Magma sources to verify the above claims:
p := 3;
QQ := Rationals();
P<x> := PolynomialRing(QQ);
K<t> := NumberField( x^20 + 12*x^15 + 36*x^10 + 324 );
OK := MaximalOrder(K);
gp := Decomposition(OK, p)[1][1];
e := RamificationIndex(gp); print "e =", e;
pi := UniformizingElement(gp);

a := 1 + pi^11; 
b := 1/5*(-5*t^19 + t^18 + 3*t^17 - t^16 - 7*t^15 - 9*t^14 
  + 7*t^13 - 6*t^12 + 7*t^11 + t^10 - 4*t^9 - 6*t^8 + 5*t^7 
  + 9*t^6 - 9*t^5 + 3*t^4 - 3*t - 4);
print "a =", K!a, "d(a) >=", Valuation(a - b^p, gp);
R<X> := PolynomialRing(K);
f := X^p - a; 
L := ext< K | f >; OL := MaximalOrder(L);
#Decomposition(OL, gp);

And here are Sage sources that do the same and return the same results:
p = 3
P.<x> = QQ[]
K.<t> = NumberField( x^20 + 12*x^15 + 36*x^10 + 324 )
gp = K.primes_above(p)[0]
e = gp.ramification_index(); print( "e =", e )
pi = K.uniformizer(gp)

a = 1 + pi^11; 
b = 1/5*(-5*t^19 + t^18 + 3*t^17 - t^16 - 7*t^15 - 9*t^14 
  + 7*t^13 - 6*t^12 + 7*t^11 + t^10 - 4*t^9 - 6*t^8 + 5*t^7 
  + 9*t^6 - 9*t^5 + 3*t^4 - 3*t - 4);
print( "a =", a, "d(a) >=", (a - b^p).valuation(gp) )
R.<X> = K[]
f = X^p - a
L.<s> = K.extension(f)
La = L.absolute_field(names = "s")
len(La.primes_above(p))

Edit: I Corrected the example; somehow, I copied it incorrectly in the first place, as Aphelli noticed. $\mathfrak{p}^5 = p\cdot \mathbb{Z}_K$.

How exactly do you see that $3\mathcal{O}_K$ is a prime ideal? It’s really not. The ramification index at $3$ is most certainly not equal to $1$, it’s probably equal to $5$. Given this extremely egregious mistake, I think you would do well to take another careful look at what you did…

Apart from using Hensel's lemma to understand that everything sufficiently near a $p$th power is likewise, we can also (really, equivalently) use $\mathfrak p$-adic exponential and logarithm to understand how close something has to be to $1$ to be guaranteed to be a $p$th power... Too many chances to mess-up data entry, etc., in wanting to see this super-explicitly, I think.

Why would the given factorization of $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}L$ prevent the existence of an embedding $L \subset K{\mathfrak{p}}$? In fact, it looks pretty clearly like $L_{\mathfrak{p}1}=K{\mathfrak{p}}$, no?

@Aphelli: Somehow, I copied the example wrongly in the first place. Yes, of course, the ramification index is $e = 5$, as it was evident from the rest of the example (i.e., $11 > 10 - 2e$). Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

@Aphelli: We have just one extension of $\mathfrak{p}$ from $K$ to its completion. I convinced myself (apparently wrongly) that it, thus, may not split in an intermediate field into more than one valuation. Topic to be closed.  (Another question would be if we can detect if $a$ is a $p$-th power looking just at ideals of $L$ over $\mathfrak{p}$.)
